# Projection matrix generalized to projection to a surface?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, geometry, projective-geometry

A projection matrix can project a vector into a plane, but is it possible to generalize this such that it can project into a surface instead of a plane?

Comment: you mean curved surface?

Comment: A projection matrix $P$ necessarily determines a linear projection by $v\mapsto P\cdot v$ the range of which is necessarily a linear subspace. However, there do exist *nonlinear* projections as well, to arbitrary surfaces, but those can hardly be represented by a single matrix..

Comment: @Berci Thank you. Could you point to some references for nonlinear projection?